# What's the difference between := and = in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> set @num := 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @num = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @num;
+------+
| @num |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Seems both works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, when using `SET` they both act as assignment operators, but in any non-set statements, `:=` is for assingment and `=` checks for *equality*.

> For SET, either = or := can be used as the assignment operator.
>
> You can also assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. In this case, the assignment operator must be := and not = because = is treated as a comparison operator in non-SET statements

```
mysql> SET @t1=1, @t2=2, @t3:=4;
mysql> SELECT @t1, @t2, @t3, @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3;
+------+------+------+--------------------+
| @t1  | @t2  | @t3  | @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3 |
+------+------+------+--------------------+
|    1 |    2 |    4 |                  7 | 
+------+------+------+--------------------+
```

Taken from [**MySQL 8.4 User Defined Variables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Is that a valid MySQL statement? Can you define variables like that?

Comment: For the sake of anyone reading these comments, it's not deprecated.  And thanks @AnthonyForloney for disseminating the basics.  This is why I love stackoverflow.

Comment: @billynoah You're welcome! Thanks for clarifying whether the syntax is deprecated or not.

Answer (score 2):

Both are assignment operator.

:= was created to be clearer since = is also an equivalence operator in SQL.  `WHERE x = 1;`  (most computer languages it is `==`)

Comment: heh.. which begs the question, why the heck didn't the just use `==` and `=` like the rest of the universe?